# Winter Summer Bash 2022 is almost here!

Tags: discussion

The most entertaining time to engage with Stack Exchange communities is during the annual "Bash" -- now being referred to as "Winter Summer Bash 2022".

See [this Meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384281/352329) which contains a link countdown clock for the event.

If you've never tried to earn hats before, have a go this year.  It's good innocent fun and helps the community to grow as well.